# Not able to read notifications from other apps

Tags: android, notifications, notificationservices

I want to read notifications from other apps in android , but I am not able to do so. These are my implementations to achieve same.
This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.demoapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TableLayout tab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tab = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
            textview.setTextSize(20);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B0719"));
            textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(pack +"<br><b>" + title + " : </b>" + text));
            tr.addView(textview);
            tab.addView(tr);




        }
    };
}
```

This is my NotificationService class

```
package com.example.demoapp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }

}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.demoapp">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.demoapp.NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab" />
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tested app in Android 5 and above, it is not getting any notification details.  I gave permission to the app for reading permissions in android while testing on Android 6 and above versions.
Suggest me where I am getting wrong.

Comment: I think you have to read this post https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/11/reading-notification-using-notificationlistenerservice.html

Comment: It has been implemented from same source

Comment: Maybe you didn't enable the Notification listener from setting menu, turn on and then try.

Comment: I have enabled it, it is showing package name in debugging too, but not displaying that, it is crashing at onNotificationPosted method in Bundle extras initialisation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created a small demo for you its working fine in Android API-18 and above devices.

Even you can

1. Read all incoming SMS
2. Read all incoming calls
3. Battery Low and other notifications too

This is screenshot for display notification of other application [Picture1](http://prntscr.com/nwxdjl) [Picture2](http://prntscr.com/nwxxol)

***NotificationService.java***

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);
        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model> modelList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
            //int id = intent.getIntExtra("icon",0);

            Context remotePackageContext = null;
            try {
                byte[] byteArray =intent.getByteArrayExtra("icon");
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                if(byteArray !=null) {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                }
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setName(title +" " +text);
                model.setImage(bmp);

                if(modelList !=null) {
                    modelList.add(model);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {
                    modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
                    modelList.add(model);
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demoapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.demoapp.NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi , it worked actually I was working on Android 8, so the ticker text was coming null and showing null pointer exception. This was the issue, 
     if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }

Comment: Yes, that's Right.

Comment: @MayurPatel Is there anyway to find out which activity should handle the notification? As you know there're apps (As phone & contacts) that share the same package name.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy No that's not possible

Comment: @MayurPatel Thanks for this answer. I'm not a Java programmer -- but I'd really like to get your demo working to see whether I should learn some Java to get an idea working.

I can't figure out how to get your code to build in Android Studio. It fails with errors in Androidmanifest.xml. I've fixed some XML that it didn't like but it still fails on '@drawable/ic_launcher'.

I should admit that all I've done so far is to copy your code into what look like the obvious places in a 'Basic Activity' project. Please can you give me some advice about where to put everything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @James Do you face issue with '@drawable/ic_launcher' this? if yes then you can replace with '@mipmap/ic_launcher' because i have just copy the code from the question and make some changes and posted as a answer.

Comment: @MayurPatel Hello and thanks. I've changed that but it fails with lots of errors.The first is that android.support.v4.content does not exist, and then there are many more errors ("cannot find symbol class Model" etc.). I suspect I've done something stupid that would be obvious to a proper Java user. Would you be willing to write a comment with a quick idiot's guide to getting it to build? Or to send a link to download the working project files? Thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @James it would be great if you have share your project or demo with me so i can look it and resolved your issue.